# Change the date time format in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I wanted to change the date time format in pandas with the code

```
tmdb_data.release_date = pd.to_datetime(tmdb_data['release_date'])`
```

However, I am getting an error message like this

```
Unknown string format
```

Please help.

Comment: Check your data. It seems that there are cells with a format different than a date, you may have a word instead of 2018-12-14 if this is your date format.

Comment: Could you please provide the example of input data. Based on your input you can try parameters in pd.to_datetime function like day_first, error

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have a date format like 06/9/15.